# Push Notifications without a frontend?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have this app which reads a third party (not mine in any way) JSON file from the internet. When a value goes above a certain value in the JSON file I want a Push notification to show up. Would I need a frontend server to scan the JSON file and then send the Push Notifications to the iPhone? Is there a way of doing it without a Push Notification?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a server to read that JSON, you'll have to read it in your app. This means you'll only be able to do it when your app is running in the foreground.

If you want to display a notification based on that JSON even when your app is not running, you'll have to read the JSON in your server and send a push notification to the app based on it.

Comment: So I can do it aslong as the app is running in the background? If so what would I use to display a notification? Im currently using CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert which I know Apple doesnt allow

Comment: @JamerTheProgrammer No, you can't. Apple allows you to run apps in the **background** in very specific cases (such as VoIP, playing music and location tracking), and your case is not one of them. You can only do it in the app if the app is running in the **foreground**.